# woocommerce custom "Add to cart" text/link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How can I change the "Add to cart" button text/link in woocommerce (v2.4)?

I tried to add this code to my functions.php, but it doesn´t seem to work:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');

function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    $text = _( 'Learn More', 'woocommerce' );
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">Learn more</a>';
}
```

Comment: Same answer as below -> Doesn´t work anymore

Comment: If you search a little bit, here 2 links that are **official snippets code from WooThemes** the makers of WooCommerce : [**WooThemes - Change add to cart button text (all solutions)**](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/) and [WooThemes - Change "Add to Cart" button in Shop page](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203006565-Change-Add-to-Cart-button-to-Go-to-Product-in-the-Shop-Page)

Answer (score 1):

It was asked for WC 2.4. If you need it for newer versions you should use

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text',function(){
    return __( 'Learn more','your-textdomain' );
} );
```

Tested with WooCOmmerce 5.6

Answer (score 0):

You have written correct code, but before using `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` hook, you have to remove "add to cart" button using same hook as shown below.

Step 1 - Remove "add to cart" button from shop

```
function remove_loop_button(){
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );
}
add_action('init','remove_loop_button');
```

Step 2 -Add new button that links to product page for each product

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo do_shortcode('<a href="'.$link.'" class="button addtocartbutton">Learn more</a>');
}
```

Comment: Yes, same outdated solution as here (please read comments): https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203006565-Change-Add-to-Cart-button-to-Go-to-Product-in-the-Shop-Page ... For some reason Step 1 doesn´t remove the "Add to cart" button.

Comment: @user2196602, checkout my updated answer. Added one more `remove_action`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! `woocommerce_single_product_summary` removes everything (quantity, variations etc. - not only the button). `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` seems not to do anything.

Comment: @user2196602, okay then try to add `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false );` maybe it should work, https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/the-right-way-to-hide-add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce/ Read this for more details. updated my answer.

Comment: `'woocommerce_is_purchasable', false ` removes quantity and button. I only want to change the button.

Comment: The last option i suggest you to change text/link using jQuery. I know its patch but sometimes its the last and best option. :)

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer to hide the button in a proper way :) Do you know how I could add a custom button again?

Comment: @user2196602, to use custom button again use `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` as my answer showing.

Answer (score 0):

To change you add to cart button text paste this code in your theme functions.php

```
add_filter( 'add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );                // < 2.1
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text' );  // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_single_add_to_cart_text() {

    return __( 'Learn More', 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line of code needs to be added to the functions.php

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart');
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart');
```

This is for removing the product from product listing page.

@Lorenz I think you should go through this https://www.wpblog.com/add-to-cart-button-in-woocommerce-store/